# How To Declare Fixed Length String Value In PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, varchar

In PL/SQL strings are declared in two different ways. These ways are fixed-length strings declaration, variable-length strings declaration. If we need to declare a variable-length string, we must provide the maximum length of that string. For example, the VARCHAR2 data type.

```
DECLARE
 /*VARIABLE LENGTH STRING DECLARATION*/
   name varchar2(20);
   company varchar2(30);
 /*FIXED LENGTH STRING DECLARATION*/
   choice char(2) DEFAULT 'y';
BEGIN
   name := 'John Smith';
   company := 'Infotech';
   IF choice = 'y' THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(name);
      dbms_output.put_line(company);
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Above example all string variables are declared with variable-length string declaration. Namely 'name' and 'company' strings can have 1,2,3,4,5,.....20 character. So that they are variable-length strings.

To declare a fixed-length string, we should use the CHAR datatype. Here we do not have to specify a maximum length for a fixed-length variable. If we leave off the length constraint, Oracle Database automatically uses a maximum length required.

```
DECLARE
/*FIXED LENGTH STRING DECLARATION*/
   fixed_length_variable CHAR := 'y';
BEGIN
   IF fixed_length_variable = 'y' THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Oracle Database automatically uses a maximum length for fixed length variable');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Now i want to declare string with fixed-length variable declaration. It has a more than one word.

```
DECLARE
    /*I CAN'T USE CHAR DATA TYPE. BECAUSE VALUE HAS MORE CHARACTERS*/
    fixed_length_declaration VARCHAR2 := 'Fixed Declaration';
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(fixed_length_declaration);
END;
/
```

When i want to try this example, ORACLE  throw 'ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)' error. How can i make fixed length declaration with 'fixed_length_declaration' variable which is declared in the above code. How can i fix this error ? Must i use CHAR datatype to make fixed length declaration in PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is vague at best...  But in Oracle, `CHAR` is analogous to `CHAR(1)` ..

All of this information can easily be found in the oracle documentation (which is probably why you have down votes .. if you spent a bit of time in the oracle documentation for data types, you'd have your answers), but I will explain the difference between varchar and char here..

`CHAR` datatype is for fixed length strings, period.  All strings within a `CHAR` field are the length of the field.  So a `CHAR(4)` of `'y'` would ACTUALLY be stored as `'y   '` (with buffering spaces to fill up the length).  The only reason your test works above is because your `CHAR` is the same as `CHAR(1)`.

`VARCHAR2` datatype is for variable length strings, period.  All strings within a `VARCHAR2` field are the length of the string that was given.  So a `VARCHAR2(4)` of `'y'` would ACTUALLY be stored as `'y'` (with a tiny bit of additional information saying that the data is "x" bytes long).

There are very few situations where you would prefer a `CHAR` field over a `VARCHAR2` field.

What @a_horse_with_no_name is trying to suggest is that you should be able to just declare your variable as `VARCHAR2(20)` and be done with it. If, for some reason, 20 is TOO SHORT, then just declare it to be a larger size. If you don't know how large it should be, then declare it maximum size (`VARCHAR2(32767)` for PL/SQL)